# Issues with latest update for ubuntu 12

Tags: updates

Hi I have been using 12 since the release and it has been running awesome and i really like unity however after the latest update involving something to do with the kernel (i have know idea what it was i should have read it first) Libre calc and Firefox have been running extremely slow, too the point of crashing. Is there anyway to revert an update without reinstalling 12 from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Its unlikely to by due to the kernel but you can always choose the old one . As your machine boots up hold **shift** and you will get a menu. You can see what else was installed by using **log-file viewer** or opening /var/log/dpkg.log in a text editor.

Comment: *update* rebooted computer working great thanks for the quick reply!!